# Get users home directory when they run a script as root

Tags: bash, shell

I have a sh script that needs to be run as root, however it is run by the end user using sudo. How can I get the users home directory when ~/ points to /root when running with sudo?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The user's home directory would be `~$SUDO_USER`. You can use `eval` as follows:

```
USER_HOME=$(eval echo ~${SUDO_USER})
echo ${USER_HOME}
```

Comment: Try to avoid `eval`. See my answer without `eval`.

Comment: You don't need the `eval` here.  The `~` is shell expansion, so `echo ~user` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, you do need `eval` because the user is stored in a variable.

Comment: try before running this code `SUDO_USER='root; touch /tmp/AllYourBaseAreBelongToUs'`

Comment: @MichałŠrajer Eval generally is a codesmell, but it should be safe in this context -- sudo should set SUDO_USER to a safe value (a legal username) and if something runs with a pwned sudo or without sudo but with a pwned environment, then the "whole your program are belong to h3x0r".

Answer (score 52):

Try to avoid eval. Especially with root perms.

You can do:

```
USER_HOME=$(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6)
```

**Update:**

[here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) is why to avoid eval.

Comment: I rolled back the original post. Suggested simplification was incorrect.

Comment: @downvoter: If you downvote, then please leave the comment what's wrong in your opinion. Otherwise it's non constructive. Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote was due to the lack of explanation towards avoiding eval? I would quite like to know the reasons for avoiding it now!

Comment: @bunnyDrug `eval` is unsafe because it executes the resulting string after parameter expansions. `FOO="bob; ls"; eval "echo $FOO"` only prints one word: "bob", then executes `ls`. Now replace `ls` with something more nefarious.

Comment: If you want this to always work, regardless of whether the user is running with sudo or not, you could use `USER_HOME=$(getent passwd ${SUDO_USER:-$USER} | cut -d: -f6)`

Answer (score 9):

```
$ sudo env |grep USER
USER=root
USERNAME=root
SUDO_USER=glglgl
```

So you can access `$SUDO_USER` and ask the system for his homedir with `getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6`.

Answer (score 4):

Try accessing the environment variable $SUDO_USER

Comment: Example: `sudo sh -c 'echo ~$SUDO_USER'`

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstood the question, when the user runs the script with sudo, the `$HOME` environment variable does not change. To test out, I created this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#sudo_user.sh
env | grep -e USER -e HOME
```

... and run it:

```
sudo ./sudo_user.sh
```

Output:

```
USER=root
HOME=/home/haiv
USERNAME=root
SUDO_USER=haiv
```

The output tells me that `$HOME` is still pointing to the user's home (in this case, */home/haiv*).

Comment: This is not true on Debian server, the `$HOME` changes. `$SUDO_USER` will reveal the actual user, though.

Answer (score 0):

It comes to a little improvement for the eval solution.

Before sending the username variable to `eval`, test it with the user existence, so if there's arbitrary code, it won't pass the check.

```
#? Description:
#?   Get the user's home directory by username regardless of whether is running with `sudo`.
#?   The username is checked, it must exist, to avoid the arbitrary code execution of `eval`.
#?   The returned home directory's existence is not checked.
#?
#? Usage:
#?   @home USERNAME
function home () {
    if id "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        eval echo "~$1"
    else
        return 255
    fi
}
```

Run the code on macOS:

```
$ home root
```

Output:

```
/var/root
```

If you run it with something like:

```
home 'root ; ls'
```

It gives nothing and returns an error, the `ls` won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hai's incomplete answer to very simply construct the user's home directory. He and others correctly state that you can get the original user while in the sudo shell. You can use that to construct the home directory into a new variable called user_home (or whatever you like):

```
#user_home="/home/${$SUDO_USER}";
```

Comment: What if a user has a nonstandard location for their home dir? Wouldn’t it be smarter to obtain the actual home dir rather than guess that it’s under /home?