# Why does the output differ when executed from a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358611/bash-get-users-home-directory-when-they-run-a-script-as-root) post, I run this from the command line:

```
USER_HOME=$(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6)
```

and get the following output:

```
/root
/usr/sbin
/bin
/dev
/bin
/usr/games
/var/cache/man
/var/spool/lpd
/var/mail
/var/spool/news
/var/spool/uucp
/bin
/var/www
/var/backups
/var/list
/var/run/ircd
/var/lib/gnats
/nonexistent
/var/lib/libuuid
/home/user
/var/run/vboxadd
/var/lib/puppet
/var/run/sshd
```

When I run this in a script (as `sudo`, which is the point of the whole thing --- as sudo, `~` expands to `/root`):

```
USER_HOME=$(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6)
echo $USER_HOME
```

I get my correct path `/home/user`.

**Why can I not invoke my function manually to get the same output?**

Comment: This is probably better asked over at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: This command is designed to run by `sudo`. How are you running it from the command line?

Comment: I don't understand.  When I run `getent passwd user | cut -d: -f6` as an ordinary for any value of `user`, I just get the user's home directory, not all of the stuff you cited.  What is the value of $SUDO_USER?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when not using `sudo`, `$SUDO_USER` is not set and you get the output of `getent passwd` without further argument, which lists all users. The `cut` then extracts the home directory part.

Replace `$SUDO_USER` with `$USER` when not running with `sudo`.

Note that using `getent passwd ${SUDO_USER:-$USER}` should work in both cases.